# Combining duplicate rows with different values in columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script written to import a CSV of my client's product inventory. The problem is there's a bug in the software they use to track their inventory that will duplicate a product with different values for their inventory.

So when I import the CSV they send me there are duplicate rows of the same product with different inventories. Example:

```
id  |  product  |  cases  | unit
--------------------------------
1   |  MF003    |   3     |  7
2   |  MF004    |   5     |  6
3   |  MF005    |   1     |  9
4   |  MF005    |   7     |  2
5   |  MF006    |   2     |  1
```

The MF005 product has two rows. What I need is this:

```
id  |  product  |  cases  | unit
--------------------------------
1   |  MF003    |   3     |  7
2   |  MF004    |   5     |  6
3   |  MF005    |   8     |  11
5   |  MF006    |   2     |  1
```

You'll notice that MF005 is now one row with both cases and units added up correctly.

I suppose the better approach here would be to do this using a SELECT query instead of dealing with it beforehand via INSERT, but if there's a smarter way to do this by INSERTing, I'm definitely open to it.

Comment: Your question is "How can I Summarize Cases And Unit Where Product is a Duplicate"

Comment: You can use a [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You would need to make `product` a `UNIQUE KEY`. Then you could do `INSERT INTO yourTable (id,product,cases,unit) VALUES (4,'MF005',7,2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cases = VALUES(cases), unit = VALUES(unit)`

Comment: **correction for above** - that should be `... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cases = cases+VALUES(cases), unit = unit+VALUES(unit)`

Comment: @Sean - going to try this. Thanks!

Comment: @Sean - this totally worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert and update at once:

```
CREATE TABLE importdata(
  id INT,
  product VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT "" PRIMARY KEY,
  cases INT,
  unit INT
);

INSERT INTO importdata(id,product,cases,unit) VALUES (3,"MF005",1,9) ON 
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cases=cases+1, unit=unit+9;
```

Results in:

```
3   |  MF005    |   1     |  9
```

Executing the second insert:

```
INSERT INTO importdata(id,product,cases,unit) VALUES (4,"MF005",7,2) ON 
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cases=cases+7, unit=unit+2;
```

Results in:

```
3   |  MF005    |   8     |  11
```

Comment: This might work. Going to try to adapt this, thanks!